# Doubt on the M87* Image

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon

In a layman sense we called that the black spot of [M87*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_87#Supermassive_black_hole_M87*) image is the event horizon. But in some technical references [1] the author said that the black spot actually delimits the photon sphere. I would like to know what is, precisely, that black spot on M87* image: Is the event Horizon or the Photon Sphere?

$$* * *$$
Feel free to be mathematically precise.

$[1]$ GRENZEBACH A. *The Shadow of Black Holes*.Springer.2016

Comment: It is the photon sphere.

Comment: Ok...but how can I see this mathematically?

Comment: You can start here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere

Comment: The apparent shadow radius is about √27 GM/c² (which is the critical impact parameter for light rays in the vicinity of a Schwarzschild black hole).  If you want it mathematically precise see http://gravitylense.yukterez.net and http://raytracing.yukterez.net

Comment: Why do you say doubt, when you mean question?